# How to add JavaScript event listener to first element of an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I have simply an unordered list am trying to create with html5 and javascript, I want to add events to this list element eg first element.

Here is my HTML list:

```
<ul class="aside__list">
    <li class="one">Kutomba kuma</li>
    <li class="two">Kutomba tako</li>
    <li class="three">Kutomba mkundu</li>
    <li class="four">Kutomba malaya</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var parentElements = document.getElementsByClassName('aside__list');
for (var i=0; i<parentElements.length; i++) {        
    parentElements[i].addEventListener('click', doStuff, false);
    console.log(parentElements[i]);
}

function doStuff() {
    alert('Delete me');
}
```

I want to add an event to the first element of my list using for loop without using a class or id,  now this event applies to every list element in my list,

what do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: Your code makes a classic performance mistake, not only by using `.getElementsByClassName()`, but by referencing the live node list returned by it inside of a loop. See **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)** for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.querySelector('ul.aside__list li').addEventListener('click', doStuff);
```

This matches the first `li` so you don't need to include `:first-child`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a listener to the `li` which is the first child of the list, instead of to every whole `.aside__list`:

```js
document.querySelector('.aside__list li:first-child').addEventListener('click', doStuff);

function doStuff() {
  console.log('Delete me');
}
```

```html
<ul class="aside__list">
  <li class="one">Kutomba kuma</li>
  <li class="two">Kutomba tako</li>
  <li class="three">Kutomba mkundu</li>
  <li class="four">Kutomba malaya</li>
</ul>
```

As comment notes, the `:first-child` psuedo-selector isn't *necessary* since `querySelector` will only return the first matching element, though it may make the code's intent a bit clearer.

Comment: Semi-related, `:first-child` shouldn't be necessary, as `querySelector` only matches a single element anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This would work for any number of `ul.aside__list`:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.aside__list')].forEach(
  ul => ul.firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', doStuff)
);

function doStuff() {
  console.log('Delete me');
}
```

```html
<ul class="aside__list">
  <li class="one">Kutomba kuma</li>
  <li class="two">Kutomba tako</li>
  <li class="three">Kutomba mkundu</li>
  <li class="four">Kutomba malaya</li>
</ul>
<ul class="aside__list">
  <li class="one">Kutomba kuma</li>
  <li class="two">Kutomba tako</li>
  <li class="three">Kutomba mkundu</li>
  <li class="four">Kutomba malaya</li>
</ul>
<ul class="aside__list">
  <li class="one">Kutomba kuma</li>
  <li class="two">Kutomba tako</li>
  <li class="three">Kutomba mkundu</li>
  <li class="four">Kutomba malaya</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not just `querySelectorAll('.aside__list li')`? The end result is the same, and it avoids fetching the entire list.

Comment: @jhpratt Because that would select all list items inside each list.

Comment: Whoops, tack a `:first-child` on the end of that then.

Comment: Can you explain why did you choose to use `foreach` and not `for loop` as question suggest?

Comment: Because it's more readable, does not require an index variable and lets you access the iterated elements without using the clunky `element[i]`  syntax.

Comment: @jhpratt `document.querySelectorAll('.aside__list li:first-child').length === document.querySelectorAll('.aside__list').length`.